# Connect AWS S3 to Databricks PySpark

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to connect and read all my csv files from s3 bucket with databricks pyspark. When I am using some bucket that I have admin access , it works without error

```
data_path = 's3://mydata_path_with_adminaccess/'
```

But when I tried to connect to some bucket which needs ACCESS_KEY_ID and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY , It will not work and access is denied :

I tried :

```
data_path = 's3://mydata_path_without_adminaccess/'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='my key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='my key'
```

and:

```
data_path = ='s3://<MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID>:<My_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>@mydata_path_without_adminaccess
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not really sure if you have tried mounting your bucket in databricks using secret and keys , but it's worth trying:

Here is the code for the same:

```
ACCESS_KEY = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "aws", key = "aws-access-key")
SECRET_KEY = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "aws", key = "aws-secret-key")
ENCODED_SECRET_KEY = SECRET_KEY.replace("/", "%2F")
AWS_BUCKET_NAME = "<aws-bucket-name>"
MOUNT_NAME = "<mount-name>"

dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s:%s@%s" % (ACCESS_KEY, ENCODED_SECRET_KEY, AWS_BUCKET_NAME), "/mnt/%s" % MOUNT_NAME)
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/%s" % MOUNT_NAME))
```

and then you can access files in your S3 bucket as if they were local files:

```
df = spark.read.text("/mnt/%s/...." % MOUNT_NAME)
```

Additional reference:

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried mounting as well but got the error "Secret does not exist with scope: aws and key". While I can connect my python session with that scret keys!

Answer (score 2):

To connect S3 with databricks using access-key, you can simply mount S3 on databricks. It creates a pointer to your S3 bucket in databricks.
If you already have a secret stored in databricks, Retrieve it as below:

```
access_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "aws", key = "aws-access-key")
secret_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "aws", key = "aws-secret-key")
```

If you do not have a secret stored in Databricks,  try below piece of code to avoid "Secret does not exist with scope" error

```
access_key = "your-access-key"
secret_key = "your-secret-key"

#Mount bucket on databricks
encoded_secret_key = secret_key.replace("/", "%2F")
aws_bucket_name = "s3-bucket-name"
mount_name = "Mount-Name"
dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s:%s@%s" % (access_key, encoded_secret_key, aws_bucket_name), "/mnt/%s" % mount_name)
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/%s" % mount_name))
```

Access your S3 data as below

```
mount_name = "mount-name"
file_name="file name "
df = spark.read.text("/mnt/%s/%s" % (mount_name , file_name))
df.show()
```